# PHP - Adding a character instead of a comma

Tags: php

I have the following string, this is written froma database, so im not sure what the values are, but an example would be

```
my name, his name, their name, testing, testing
```

What i want to do is take out the last comma and add a space and the word 'and' so it appears as follows:

```
my name, his name, their name, testing and testing
```

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `preg_replace` to match the last comma and its surrounding space(if any) and replace it with `' and '`:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*(?!.*,)/',' and ',$input);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/eS2qP)

Explanation:

```
\s*     : Optional whitespace
,       : A literal comma
\s*     : Optional whitespace
(?!.*,) : Negative lookahead. It says match the previous pattern( a comma 
          surrounded by optional spaces) only if it is not followed 
          by another comma.
```

Alternatively you can use a greedy regex with `preg_match` as:

```
$input = preg_replace('/(.*)(?:\s*,\s*)(.*)/','\1 and \2',$input);
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/xoxEV)

Explanation:

```
(.*)        : Any junk before the last comma
(?:\s*,\s*) : Last comma surrounded by optional whitespace
(.*)        : Any junk after the last comma
```

The key here is to use a greedy regex `.*` to match the part before the last comma. The greediness will make `.*` match all but the last comma.

Comment: and that would only get rid of the last comma ?

Comment: @Chris: Yes. You can see the ideone links I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
$string = "my name, his name, their name, testing, testing";
$string_array = explode(', ', $string);

$string  = implode(', ', array_splice($string_array, -1));
$string .= ' and ' . array_pop($string_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$list="my name, his name, their name, testing, testing";
$result = strrev(implode(strrev(" and"), explode(",", strrev($list), 2)));
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Codaddict's answer is valid, but it's easier to use strrpos if you're not familiar with regexps:

```
$old_string = 'my name, his name, their name, testing, testing';
$last_index = strrpos($old_string, ',');
if ($last_index !== false) $new_string = substr($old_string, 0, $last_index) . ' and' . substr($old_string, $last_index + 1);
```